# Get certain date index values in a dataframe based on conditions met

Tags: python, date, indexing

python newb here.

I have a CSV with Date and Prices. The date is the index column.
I have a dataframe called `data`, with a column called `'Buy'` which has only True and False values.
I want a column showing the associated indexed date only if True values.

I tried the following code:

```
data['Result'] = numpy.where(data['Buy'] == True, data.index, 0)
```

But I get the message: `"The DType <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'>.`  This means that no common `DType` exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the `dtype` is `object`."

Any idea how to resolve and keep the `data['Result']` in date format? (since I need to do further calculations on the dates).

Comment: Have you tried `data[data['Buy'] == True].index`?

Comment: show example input - output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to assign both **integer** and **datetime** values ​​to a column. Pandas cannot decide which type this column is. Therefore, you should combine them in a common data type:

```
data['Result'] = numpy.where(data['Buy'] == True, data.index.astype(str), 0)
#Result dtype: object
```

if you want to datetime column you can use **pd.NaT** instead of 0:

```
data['Result'] = numpy.where(data['Buy'] == True, data.index.astype(str), pd.NaT)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. So its the different data types. Your solution worked.

Comment: Accepting/upvoting is Stackoverflow synonym of Thanks. So please accept or upvote if answer worked for you.